# Which is an appropriate location to create a Folder in c# console application for reading and writing to files?

Tags: c#, build, appdomain

I'm working on a c# console application which is going to download data into files (say under 'Files' folder) and then later read those files. Common option is to read from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. However, depending upon whether project is build in Debug or Release mode, directory would change.
So what is it is advisable to create a 'Files' folder like ~\bin\Debug\Files and while deploying to server, as ~\bin\Release\Files?

Comment: `Path.GetTempPath()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-7.0&tabs=windows

Comment: I wouldn't want to put in temp directory since eventually it will be on the server.

Comment: The server also has a temp directory, why wouldn't you be able to use that?

Comment: Someone could accidentally delete files from temp. I would rather place it in the project root folder. How can I get path for project root folder?

Comment: `Enviroment.CurrentDirectory` then?

Comment: This is giving absolute path ending in \bin\debug

Comment: What's wrong with that, isn't that what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to find relative path of project

Comment: Relatve to what?? The application runs from that folder, that is the absolute path. The relative path would be just `.\yourApplication.exe` And why do you need the relative path, you have the correct path anyway?

Comment: For example path to proj is C:\MyProjects\MyProj\bin\Debug

I would like to create folder 'Files' under MyProj. Question is, how to get to ~\MyProj\Files

Comment: Are these user-specific files, or application-specific files. If the latter, use a folder you create under `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`. If specific to a user,  use `.LocalApplicationData` instead

Comment: You really don't want to write to something relative to the deployed application. If you deploy this to `ProgramFiles`, standard users do not have write rights to those locations.  You also don't want to be relative to `C:\MyProjects\MyProj` , once you deploy your app, your users won't know anything about where you developed it

Comment: these are application specific files. Users wont have access to those.